# Finding APL symbols on the keyboard

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I use GNU APL on Debian 10. My Apple keyboard is configured to input APL characters using the right Alt key and the latter is remapped to the right Command key:

```
setxkbmap se,apl -variant ,dyalog -option grp:switch -option lv3:rwin_switch
```

I can now type APL characters like ⍴ (rho) and ⍳ (iota) with **RightAlt+R** and **RightAlt+I** respectively. However, many APL symbols have a less intuitive placement on the keyboard so I would like to see where each symbol is located. I have tried using xkeycaps* but it shows no APL characters. Any clues?

*I use the following keyboard setting

> PC -> 105 key, wide Delete, tall Enter -> XFree86; Swedish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU APL has a command ]KEYB which shows an APL keyboard layout for people that can't remember all the keys. The command does not exactly show the keyboard layout in use but rather a fixed text file with a common layout. But you can change the text that is being displayed so that it shows exactly your keyboard layout.